# Ajax Upload Image to Mysql Using "Mysqli-PHP" On server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to insert image to mysql database using PHP(Mysqli) On server side and ajax on client but when iam submitting the image
it is showing the error(s) as follows

> Warning: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in x:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\insert.php on line 3

AJAX:

```
$("form[name='frmImage']").submit(function(e) {
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);



        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);

                $('#error').html(msg);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="frmImage" method="post" action=""     enctype="multipart/form-data" >

            <input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />

    </form>

    <div id="error">
```

PHP:

```
    $db = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxxx","xxx"); //keep your db name
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));

    $query = "INSERT INTO images (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";  
    $qry = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Sql Query:

```
    CREATE TABLE `images` (
      `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `image` longblob,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It would be `$_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']` name of you file type !!

Comment: @Saty, will the php know about ajax passed image ?? My question May sound viread am new to this..

Comment: @Saty it is still not working,

Answer (score 0):

You have miss match typo for field name in php code: You file input name is `userImage` so you can get image property using `userImage`

**change**

```
$_FILES['formData']['tmp_name']
```

**To**

```
$_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: I have changed it but still shows the error(s) u can check on my updated post.

Comment: instead of file_get_content use move_uploaded_file  for more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: First of all Thanks for ur time, am new to this, i have a quick question how can my php code know that the image is passed by ajax

Comment: `Warning: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in x:\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\insert.php on line 3`  it is showing the error as above